# Using sub-query to SELECT MAX value along with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have a query for getting search results, which works fine.

#### Example of successful query:

```
 SELECT
    individuals.individual_id,
    individuals.unique_id,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,individuals.day_of_birth,CURDATE()) AS age,
    individuals_dynamics.id,
    individuals_achievements.degree
  FROM
    individuals as individuals
  LEFT JOIN
    individuals_dynamics AS individuals_dynamics ON individuals.unique_id = individuals_dynamics.individual_id
  LEFT JOIN
    individuals_achievements AS individuals_achievements ON individuals.unique_id = individuals_achievements.individual_id
  WHERE
    $uuid_access_status $display_type $detailed_search_query
  ORDER BY 
    $search_sort $search_order
```

From now on, I have more than one record in `individuals_achievements` per each individual and this is the where I would like to get the MAX value (latest id).

I tried the many different queries but always was getting an error ***Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object.***

I understand what that error means but I can't figure out where I'm making that mistake and what is wrong in general.

#### Example of my unsuccessful attempt:

```
  SELECT
    individuals.individual_id,
    individuals.unique_id,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,individuals.day_of_birth,CURDATE()) AS age,
    individuals_dynamics.id,
    individuals_achievements.degree
  FROM
    individuals as individuals
  LEFT JOIN
    individuals_dynamics AS individuals_dynamics ON individuals.unique_id = individuals_dynamics.individual_id
  INNER JOIN
  (
       SELECT
            degree, MAX(id) AS latest_record
       FROM
            individuals_achievements
       GROUP BY
            latest_record
  ) individuals_achievements AS individuals_achievements ON individuals.unique_id = individuals_achievements.individual_id
  WHERE
    $uuid_access_status $display_type $detailed_search_query
  ORDER BY 
    $search_sort $search_order
```

What am I missing here? Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your `from` clause:

```
  FROM
    individuals as individuals
  LEFT JOIN
    individuals_dynamics AS individuals_dynamics ON individuals.unique_id = individuals_dynamics.individual_id
  INNER JOIN
  (
       SELECT
            degree, MAX(id) AS latest_record
       FROM
            individuals_achievements
       GROUP BY
            latest_record
  ) individuals_achievements AS individuals_achievements ON individuals.unique_id = individuals_achievements.individual_id;
```

I can spot at least three problems.  The first is `individuals_achievements AS individuals_achievements`; the second is the reference to `individuals_achievements.individual_id` which isn't in the subquery.  The third is the `group by latest_record`.

```
  FROM individuals LEFT JOIN
       individuals_dynamics
       ON individuals.unique_id = individuals_dynamics.individual_id LEFT JOIN
       individuals_achievements
       ON individuals.unique_id = individuals_achievements.individual_id JOIN
       (SELECT ia.individual_id, MAX(ia.id) AS latest_record
        FROM individuals_achievements ia
        GROUP BY ia.individual_id
       ) iamax
       ON individuals.unique_id = iamax.individual_id and
          individuals_achievements.id = iamax.latest_record
```

This adds an additional subquery, with the id of the latest record.

By the way, it is redundant to have a table alias be the same name as the table name.  That just clutters up the query.  Also, it is a good idea to use table abbreviations for the aliases, such as `ia` for `individuals_achievements`.  Because this answer focuses only on the `from` clause, I have not made that change.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon! Your answer sounds correct! You have forgotten `degree` in the query, the main part! I will try and tell you more about what I got!

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev . . . You can still pull the degree from the `individuals_achievements` table.  The only use of the subquery is to look up the latest record.

Comment: You're right!! Just got it working the expected way! Thank you for your answer and explanations!

Comment: Gordon, I can see you're not using `AS` in your example: `FROM individuals_achievements ia` Is it the same way if you were using it, kinda short-hand?
What you don't like about `individuals_achievements AS individuals_achievements`? Maybe redundancy? Isn't more readable than short-hands? ;)

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev . . . As a matter of preference, I use `as` for column aliases and leave them out for table aliases. Visually, it helps me spot when columns are being renamed.  Databases are inconsistent on this.  Oracle does not allow `as` for table aliases; MS Access seems to require it.

Comment: Thank you again, Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

`PDO::query` returns a `FALSE` if there's an error while processing your query, and applying `rowCount` to `FALSE` as a member function will result in the error you're seeing.

Check your query for syntax errors and parse any error messages `PDO` would return you.

Comment: Thank you, Quassnoi! Like I said, I understand what that error means. It always returns the same error as I'm querying something that is not an object, because, I think of the incorrect, sub-query!

Answer (score 0):

```
INNER JOIN
  (
       SELECT
            degree, MAX(id) AS latest_record,individual_id
       FROM
            individuals_achievements
       GROUP BY
            latest_record
  ) individuals_achievements AS individuals_achievements_1 ON individuals.unique_id = individuals_achievements_1.individual_id
```

It should be

`INNER JOIN (SELECT blah) AS something 
ON individuals.unique_id=something.individual_id`

Comment: Isn't the same as in my example? What is the difference? Just using other names? It doesn't work unfortunately! Returns same error! Thank you though, for a try!

Answer (score 0):

You have to select `individual_id` in your `INNER JOIN` because that part you are using in your `ON` clause and you have selected `degree, MAX(id) AS latest_record` only and trying to join with `individual_id` which is undefined in the newly generated table by inner join

```
individuals_achievements AS individuals_achievements 
ON individuals.unique_id = individuals_achievements.individual_id
```

try this one

```
SELECT
    individuals.individual_id,
    individuals.unique_id,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,individuals.day_of_birth,CURDATE()) AS age,
    individuals_dynamics.id,
    individuals_achievements.degree
  FROM
    individuals as individuals
  LEFT JOIN
    individuals_dynamics AS individuals_dynamics ON individuals.unique_id = individuals_dynamics.individual_id
  INNER JOIN
  (
       SELECT
            degree, MAX(id) AS latest_record,individual_id
       FROM
            individuals_achievements
       GROUP BY
            latest_record
  ) individuals_achievements AS individuals_achievements_1 ON individuals.unique_id = individuals_achievements_1.individual_id
  WHERE
    $uuid_access_status $display_type $detailed_search_query
  ORDER BY 
    $search_sort $search_order
```

Make sure you do have a column `individual_id` in table `individuals_achievements`

Comment: No, my friend, it wasn't the case! I tried that! Thank you for your help, though, dianuj!

Comment: I have pointed only mistake :) and that gordon has also pointed but the more helpful was gordon's answer you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

First off you're not really using the `AS` keyword in SQL to make your query more readable, which would help. And I'm wondering what is in the (php?) variables of the `WHERE` clause.

Also, your subquery isn't returning a field `individual_id` yet you try to JOIN on it. I think you might want this:

```
SELECT
  ind.individual_id,
  ind.unique_id,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,ind.day_of_birth,CURDATE()) AS age,
  ind_dyn.id,
  ind_ach.degree
FROM
  individuals as ind
LEFT JOIN
  individuals_dynamics AS ind_dyn ON ind.unique_id = ind_dyn.individual_id
INNER JOIN
  individuals_achievements AS ind_ach 
     ON ind_ach.individual_id = ind.unique_id
    AND ind_ach.id =
    (
      SELECT MAX(id) FROM individuals_achievements
      WHERE individuals_achievements.individual_id = ind.unique_id
    )
WHERE
  $uuid_access_status $display_type $detailed_search_query
ORDER BY 
  $search_sort $search_order
```

Comment: Thank you, funkwurm! To be honest, for me, regular table names are more readable! Why would I want to use short-hands for naming it? 
I can't provide you with sub-query it's enormous!