# Trying to reproduce a MySQL query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I recently stumbled upon this thread where a user was trying to return some data using a sub query based upon the max value of another query, [Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902790/using-sub-query-to-select-max-value-along-with-left-join) this is exactly what I'd like to do.

What I'm trying to do is to pull the most recent log entry from my audit table "Modification_Log" so that I can list the most recent change date, and who made it in a more elegant way than retrieving multiple queries. I've gone into a bit more detail over here [Database Administrator's Stack](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76816/alternative-to-sub-query-in-ms-access), I'm not asking to be spoon fed but I simply have no idea what is going wrong!

```
SELECT Employee.EmployeeID, Employee.PositionID, Employee.Title, Employee.Firstname, Employee.Surname, Employee.Email,  Modification_Log.ModifiedDate, Modification_Log.ModifiedEmployee
FROM Employee INNER JOIN Modification_Log ON Employee.EmployeeID = Modification_Log.RecordID  INNER JOIN
               (SELECT Modification_Log.RecordID, Max(Modification_Log.ModificationID) As NewestModificationID
               FROM Modification_Log
               GROUP BY Modification_Log.RecordID) As LogMax
ON Employee.EmployeeID = LogMax.RecordID AND Modification_Log.ModificationID = LogMax.NewestModificationID
WHERE Employee.EmployeeID = 3 AND Modification_Log.TableName = 'Employee'
```

**EDIT: I did as @maxhugen suggested below, lo and behold.. Access in it's infinite wisdom rearranged the query to reference the joined query first, I've edited it and replaced again with the sub query, this time it works:**

```
SELECT Employee.EmployeeID, Employee.PositionID, Employee.Title, Employee.Firstname, Employee.Surname, Employee.Email, Modification_Log.ModifiedDate, Modification_Log.ModifiedEmployee
FROM 
         (SELECT Modification_Log.RecordID, Max(Modification_Log.ModificationID) As NewestModificationID
         FROM Modification_Log
         GROUP BY Modification_Log.RecordID) As LogMax 
INNER JOIN (Employee INNER JOIN Modification_Log ON Employee.EmployeeID = Modification_Log.RecordID) ON (LogMax.NewestModificationID = Modification_Log.ModificationID) AND (LogMax.RecordID = Employee.EmployeeID)
WHERE Employee.EmployeeID=3 AND Modification_Log.TableName='Employee';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't spot an error in your sql, but would suggest:

1. Create your sql subquery as a saved 'temp' query in Access. Test.
2. In a new query, add the query from (1), add one more table, link, and test.
3. Add any other tables, link, test.
4. Add criteria (WHERE).

Once you've ensured it's running OK, you can replace the query from (1) using it's SQL as a subquery within the main query sql.

Comment: Thanks Max, I did that and it rearranged my joins, I don't really see what difference it makes! but I've edited my question to show the working version. Access is silly.

Comment: From your Edit above, sounds like the query is working OK now. Were you able to determine the cause of the problem? (curious myself!)

Comment: Yes it's working now thanks. I'm really not too sure, I rearranged the query again after getting it working and can only assume that Access enforces some kind of rule on the order of joins when using a sub query. It would seem that the sub query needs to immediately follow the FROM clause otherwise throws a Syntax Error (missing operator).